# manual zoom in the enlarged image window

Tags: mobile, zooming, lightbox2

I would like to have the option of manual zoom in the enlarged image window on the mobile device. So that I can zoom into the displayed image within the Javascript frame. I do not want to zoom the whole web page. Is that possible? Or is there another Javascript that can do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve and also provide a URL or a description of the page and it usage?

Comment: When I display an enlarged image with Lightbox, I would like to be able to zoom in on this image on my smartphone. So that I can look at a section of the image. Is this now easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to zoom the enlarged image in Lightbox or Lightbox2. There is no such feature.

To do that, you should use a different zoom script, such as [Magic Zoom Plus](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/).

Comment: Thank you for your information! It's a pity that it's not possible. I think it would be a very interesting feature for Lightbox on the smartphone.